# EmberJS : Value assigned through JQuery or JavaScript not reflected in model

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, handlebars.js

> I'v working on EmberJS app and facing this very tricky problem:

I've Bind a JSON Object to form , When value entered through Key Board then working fine but if a value assign through JQuery its was successfully enter in input and display but this value not refelect in JSON Object.

JSON Object:

```
var obj = {
            ctry_id: "",
            ctryl_name: "",
        };
```

Ember Route:

```
setupController: function (controller, model) {
        controller.set('obj', obj);

},
```

HandelBar View:

```
{{input id="ctryl_name" type="text"  value=ctryl_name name="ctryl_name"  class="form-control" }}
```

jQuery:

```
$('#ctryl_name').val('text valu');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I've faced this problem and fixed with Ember.set:**

```
var ctryl_name  = $('#ctryl_name').val(); //get text box value

Ember.set(obj, "ctryl_name", ctryl_name); //set ember object value
```

Hope that will help for you :)

Comment: its fine but i'm waiting for some more answers

Answer (score 0):

This line is wrong :

```
`{{input id="ctryl_name" type="text"  value=ctryl_name name="ctryl_name"  class="form-control" }}`
```

It should be :

```
{{input id="ctryl_name" type="text" change=(action (mut obj.ctryl_name)) value=obj.ctryl_name name="ctryl_name"  class="form-control" }}
```

Comment: no issue with syntax, Please understand my problem.

Comment: @GovindSamrow First your syntax is wrong. You didn't bind `obj.ctryl_name` to `{{input}}`. Second any changes should be done through actions to affect. So I update my answer